# How far away can you see a bonfire?

Tags: atmosphere, vision

From how far can you see a bonfire...

in clear weather/slight mist/heavy mist,

at midday/dusk/night?

(assuming an unobstructed line-of-sight)

Comment: This appears to be a straightforward, albeit broad question of optics.  What is the worldbuilding problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The implications here are obvious. Do we really have to write a narrative for every simple question here?

Comment: See it at the limit of human vision perception (like a magnitude 5-6 star), or see and be able to identify it as bonfire?

Comment: @SurpriseDog this looks to me like a school homework problem rather than worldbuilding, with 4 independent variables (size of fire, atmospheric conditions, background light level, degree of recognition).  If the problem was stated as "How close do my beacons summoning the Riders of Gondor need to be in order to ensure they can be seen by the next beacon under most conditions?" or "Under what weather / light conditions can a bonfire not be detectable by a person with line of sight 300 m away?" then it would be a clear worldbuilding problem.

Comment: well considering they were used in lighthouses and lighthouses visibility is generally limited by the curvature of the earth, probably for as far away as you can achieve light of sight.

Comment: Just a bit of information about lighthouses - their light sources (bulbs) are not particularly luminous. But they are very good at concentrating that light in the right direction using Fresnel lenses.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I read once that the unaided human eye can see a single candle on a hill 30 miles away, *on a clear night*.</strike>

Per [Alexander's link](https://www.technologyreview.com/2015/07/31/72658/how-far-can-the-human-eye-see-a-candle-flame/):

> the farthest distance a human eye can detect a candle flame is 2.76 kilometers.

That's 1.71 miles, in filthy Imperial units.

A bonfire emits more light, and its light will also reflect off nearby objects.

However, a simple search says that:

> For a six-foot tall person, the horizon is a little more than 3 miles (5 km) away.

So, it seems likely that the limiting factor here is more likely to be the curvature of the Earth.

And during daylight, it'll be a lot less.

Comment: Looks like the 30-miles statement was [debunked](https://www.technologyreview.com/2015/07/31/72658/how-far-can-the-human-eye-see-a-candle-flame/)

Comment: Astronauts have reported seeing desert campfires in the night, from orbit

Comment: @Innovine Got a link? I found stuff that says astros can see _wildfire smoke_ from space, but that's different. “I don’t know of any reports of anyone seeing lights from campfires, though at least one of the Mercury astronauts saw a steam train by following the smoke back to its source.” -- https://www.airspacemag.com/need-to-know/did-australians-light-signal-fires-for-the-astronauts-32397096/

Comment: Sure, both apollo 12 and 16 reported it. It's in the official transcripts. Here's a link to it being mentioned in the book "how apollo flew to the moon": https://tinyurl.com/258b869f